# Can I fix my bricked RPI3?

Tags: pi-3, power-supply, rip

I've been having problems finding a good 2A+ power supply around the house that would stay above 5 volts but no dice. So I gave up and tried powering from a bench power supply to a variable dc-dc step down. I powered it over the GPIO 5v and ground found it started drawing 3.5 amps. So I moved to powering over the micro USB port and it did the same thing but this I felt the power supply area on the RPi and found that the **D5** a *SMB5.0A* device ([Datasheet PDF](https://www.vishay.com/docs/88392/smbj.pdf)) was very hot and let off a bit of smoke. Can I just replace this guy or are there other problems that I have to look out for?

[Raspberry Pi 3 B v1.2 schematic](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rpi3/raspberry-pi-3-b-reduced-schematics.pdf) *- link broken*

#### Update:

[Current Raspberry Pi 3 B v1.2 reduced schematic](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rpi3/raspberry-pi-3-b-reduced-schematics.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the voltage suppressor that have smoked and power the board with stable 5V (e.g. USB, not that power supply of yours). If you only fried the suppressor, there's a slim chance it did its job protecting the rest of the board before dying. Unlikely, but it costs nothing to try.

Comment: Worked like a charm! now I just have to source one of those guys and boom just like new... I think...

Comment: @qwertyasdfgh Glad to hear that!

Answer (score 3):

That's an overvoltage protection, but it's intended to eat up short spikes only. If you have it fried, it's very likely random components are already damaged because of overvoltage.

Sorry to say that, but whereas you could try to replace each damaged chip, it's better to throw away the Pi and buy a new one.

Comment: When you buy your new Pi3 also buy the official 5.1Volt 2.5Amp 18Awg cable power supply. https://www.modmypi.com/raspberry-pi/power-1051/power-supplies-1088/raspberry-pi-official-universal-power-supply-5.1v-2.5a-black